# SetJmp/LongJmp: Why is this throwing a segfault?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, segmentation-fault

The following code summarizes the problem I have at the moment. My current execution flow is as follows and a I'm running in GCC 4.3.

```
jmp_buf a_buf;
jmp_buf b_buf;

void b_helper()
{
    printf("entering b_helper");
    if(setjmp(b_buf) == 0)
    {
        printf("longjmping to a_buf");
        longjmp(a_buf, 1);
    }
    printf("returning from b_helper");
    return; //segfaults right here
}
void b()
{
    b_helper();
}
void a()
{
    printf("setjmping a_buf");
    if(setjmp(a_buf) == 0)
    {
        printf("calling b");
        b();
    }
    printf("longjmping to b_buf");
    longjmp(b_buf, 1);
}
int main()
{
    a();
}
```

The above execution flow creates a segfault right after the return in b_helper. It's almost as if only the b_helper stack frame is valid, and the stacks below it are erased.

Can anyone explain why this is happening? I'm guessing it's a GCC optimization that's erasing unused stack frames or something.

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can only `longjmp()` back *up* the call stack. The call to `longjmp(b_buf, 1)` is where things start to go wrong, because the stack frame referenced by `b_buf` no longer exists after the `longjmp(a_buf)`.

From the documentation for `longjmp`:

> The longjmp() routines may not be called after the routine which called the setjmp() routines returns.

This includes "returning" through a `longjmp()` out of the function.

Comment: Is there a way to longjmp down the stack frame? Is it possible to copy the stack from b to b_helper into the heap and executing from there?

Also, why is the stack frame referenced by b_buf no longer valid after jumping up the call stack?

Comment: Once a part of the stack is released, it's completely invalid (other function calls, interrupts or whatever might overwrite the memory).

Comment: You can think of a `longjmp()` as an "extended return". A successful `longjmp()` works like a series of successive returns, unwinding the call stack until it reaches the corresponding `setjmp()`. Once the call stack frames are unwound, they are no longer valid. This is in contrast to implementations of coroutines (eg. Modula-2) or continuations (eg. Scheme) where the call stack remains valid after jumping somewhere else. C and C++ only support a single linear call stack, *unless* you use threads where you create multiple independent call stacks.

Comment: @jameszhao00 - I think that to have any hope of doing something like what it seems you're after will require dropping into assembly code. Whether it's a good idea to pursue is another question altogether.

Comment: Ah. So basically I can do a GCC force-inline of b_helper() and at the end of b_helper() longjmp back to a?

Comment: @jameszhao00: but if you are looking to do coroutines in C, take a look at http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/coroutines.html whcih describes using state variables and switch statements to get a similar effect.

Comment: Also, I don't get why after I longjmp back to a from b_helper() the b_helper() frame is still valid. According to the docs it should've been unwound.

Comment: The point is the b_helper() frame is *not* valid, and `b_buf` refers to an invalid frame. The fact that execution continues to the end of `b_helper()` is an accident.

Answer (score 6):

The standard says this about `longjmp()` (7.13.2.1 The longjmp function):

> The longjmp function restores the environment saved by the most recent invocation of
>   the setjmp macro in the same invocation of the program with the corresponding
>   jmp_buf argument. If there has been no such invocation, or if the function containing
>   the invocation of the setjmp macro has terminated execution in the interim

with a footnote that clarifies this a bit:

> For example, by executing a return statement or because another longjmp call has caused a
>   transfer to a setjmp invocation in a function earlier in the set of nested calls.

So you can't `longjmp()` back & forth across nested `setjmp`/`longjmp` sets.

Comment: If there are multiple nested scopes within a function, and setjmp() is performed within a nested scope, may one legitimately longjmp() back there if one has left the scope with the setjmp() but stayed within the same function?  Would that imply that volatile variables in a nested scope are required to hold their values if execution leaves and re-enters that scope (but stays within the function)?