# Why does the setjmp/longjmp crash on MSVC when it didn't in MinGW?

Tags: c, setjmp

I wanna use  `setjmp()`/`longjmp()` to implement a coroutine system. 
Then I decide to code a little .c file to test it. In MinGW, it's OK; I got the result I want.
But when I compile it in MSVC++, the program crashes: "access violation"

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <setjmp.h>

    jmp_buf a;
    int is_invoke=0;

    void 
    action_1()
    {
        for ( ;; ) {
          printf("hello~~~A\n");
          if(!setjmp(a)) {
            is_invoke=1;
            return;
          }  
        }
    }

    void 
    func()
    {
      if (is_invoke) {
        longjmp(a,1);
      }
      action_1();
      printf("end\n");
    }

    void 
    dummy()
    {
      ;
    }

    int 
    main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        for ( ;; )  {
          func();
          dummy();
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: I read an article awhile ago about how setjmp/longjmp really screwed up the optimizer, and once they got rid of it the program they were working on sped up significantly.

Comment: Q: What version of MSVC++?  Q: Exactly where did it crash? Did you try running in the Visual Studio debugger? Q: Were there any warnings or errors in your MSVC++ compile?

Comment: my version of MSVC is 2008. the crash in longjmp. yes.
there's no error & warning on compile. it's a runtime error

Comment: possible duplicate of [SetJmp/LongJmp: Why is this throwing a segfault?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381937/setjmp-longjmp-why-is-this-throwing-a-segfault)

Answer (score 9):

The man page for setjmp says:

> `setjmp()` saves the stack context/environment in `env` for later use by
>   `longjmp()`. The stack context will be invalidated  if  the  function 
>   which  called `setjmp()` returns.

In a simple implementation you might suppose that a `jmp_buf` contains an address to reset the stack pointer to and an address to jump to. As soon as you return from the function which saved the `jmp_buf`, the stack frame pointed to by the `jmp_buf` is no longer valid and may immediately become corrupted.

Or in other words, you can only rely on longjmp to act as a sort-of super-`return` statement - never to go deeper.

I think the reason this works for you in mingw (and for me on Linux) is implementation-specific and possibly down to luck. There is another way - have you read [Simon Tatham's evil coroutine macros](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/coroutines.html) essay?

Comment: ok~i check the setjmp's wiki: "Similarly, C99 does not require that longjmp preserve the current stack frame. ",but MSVC doesn't support c99 well---so, is it a reason for my program crash?

Comment: @TZW: No; the trouble is that you returned from the function which called `setjmp()` before calling `longjmp()`.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: so could you tell me is there a simple way to check a jmp_buf's context is valid or not,sir?

Comment: There is no simple way to do tell whether a `jmp_buf` is still valid; you have to code your program so that it is valid before you use it.  If you were using C++, you could use the constructor and destructor of a class to record the validity, but if you're using C++, you'd be extremely unwise to use `setjmp()` and `longjmp()` at all because they do not ensure that destructors are called.  That is also a problem in C (allocated resources are not released), but that was presumably something you took into account when choosing to use them.

Comment: Quoting from C++98 (what I have on hand), section §18.7 "Other runtime support" says in ¶4: _If any automatic objects would be destroyed by a thrown exception transferring
control to another (destination) point in the program, then a call to `longjmp(jbuf, val)` at the throw
point that transfers control to the same (destination) point has undefined behavior._  That severely restricts the use of `setjmp()` and `longjmp()` in C++; AFAIC, it essentially renders them unusable without incurring undefined behaviour.

Comment: so how i implement my own coroutine ?

Comment: @TZW Go read the essay I linked to in my answer, that explains very well a method you can use to give the appearance of coroutines in standard C.

Answer (score 4):

Since you're invoking undefined behaviour, it's OK for one compiler to crash and another to appear to work.  Both are correct - that's the beauty of undefined behaviour.

The trouble is that a saved context - the `jmp_buf` - only remains valid as long as the function that called `setjmp()` to set it has not returned.

The C99 standard (no longer the current standard, but this wording is unlikely to have changed significantly) says:

> §7.13.2.1 The `longjmp` function
>
> The `longjmp` function restores the environment saved by the most recent invocation of
>   the `setjmp` macro in the same invocation of the program with the corresponding
>   `jmp_buf` argument. If there has been no such invocation, or if the function containing
>   the invocation of the `setjmp` macro has terminated execution<sup>208)</sup> in the interim, or if the
>   invocation of the `setjmp` macro was within the scope of an identifier with variably
>   modified type and execution has left that scope in the interim, the behavior is undefined.
>
> <sup>208)</sup> For example, by executing a `return` statement or because another `longjmp` call has caused a
>   transfer to a `setjmp` invocation in a function earlier in the set of nested calls.

Your code is exiting from `action_1()` almost immediately, rendering the `jmp_buf` saved by `setjmp()` worthless.

---

I created this little demonstration of `setjmp()` and `longjmp()` a couple of years ago.  It may help you.

```
/*
@(#)File:           $RCSfile: setjmp.c,v $
@(#)Version:        $Revision: 1.1 $
@(#)Last changed:   $Date: 2009/10/01 16:41:04 $
@(#)Purpose:        Demonstrate setjmp() and longjmp()
@(#)Author:         J Leffler
@(#)Copyright:      (C) JLSS 2009
*/


#include <stdio.h>
#include <setjmp.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static jmp_buf target_location;

static void do_something(void)
{
    static int counter = 0;
    if (++counter % 10 == 0)
        printf("---- doing something: %3d\n", counter);
    if (counter % 1000 == 0)
    {
        printf("||-- doing_something: calling longjmp() with value -1\n");
        longjmp(target_location, -1);
    }
}

static void do_something_else(int i, int j)
{
    printf("-->> do_something_else: (%d,%d)\n", i, j);
    do_something();
    if (i > 2 && j > 2 && j % i == 2)
    {
        printf("||-- do_something_else: calling longjmp() with value %d\n", (i + j) % 100);
        longjmp(target_location, (i + j) % 100);
    }
    printf("<<-- do_something_else: (%d,%d)\n", i, j);
}

static void doing_stuff(void)
{
    int i;
    printf("-->> doing_stuff()\n");
    for (i = rand() % 15; i < 30; i++)
    {
        int j;
        do_something();
        for (j = rand() % 10; j < 20; j++)
        {
            do_something_else(i, j);
        }
    }
    printf("<<-- doing_stuff()\n");
}

static void manage_setjmp(void)
{
    printf("-->> manage_setjmp()\n");
    switch (setjmp(target_location))
    {
    case 0:
        /* Initial return - get on with doing stuff */
        doing_stuff();
        break;
    case -1:
        /* Error return - terminate */
        printf("<<-- manage_setjmp() - error return from setjmp()\n");
        return;
    default:
        /* NB: not officially possible to assign the return from setjmp() */
        printf("---- manage_setjmp() - non-error return from setjmp()\n");
        doing_stuff();
        break;
    }
    printf("<<-- manage_setjmp()\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("-->> main()\n");
    manage_setjmp();
    printf("<<-- main()\n");
    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use setjmp/longjmp for coroutines. Use makecontext/swapcontext on POSIX, or fibers (CreateFiber, etc.) on windows.