# Different behavior of setjmp/longjmp in release & debug

Tags: c++, c

This question comes from 
[SetJmp/LongJmp: Why is this throwing a segfault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381937/setjmp-longjmp-why-is-this-throwing-a-segfault)

When I use debug mode run the code it did crash as expect.
But if I use release it will output like this:

```
1 setjmping a_buf
2 calling b                // loop start
3 entering b_helper
4 longjmping to a_buf
5 longjmping to b_buf
6 returning from b_helper  // loop
2 calling b
3 entering b_helper
4 longjmping to a_buf
5 longjmping to b_buf
6 returning from b_helper
...
```

As my understanding, `longjmp` can be considered as `return` so the stack memory of `b_helper` will be erased and accessing become illegal. that make the program crash become reasonable.
But why it gives different behaviour in `release`? Looks like `return` behave as `longjmp`. 
So the result in release shall be the right and my understanding is wrong.

Mingw: 5.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in question causes [undefined behaviour](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).  The program is incorrect, there is no expected behaviour.   You should not expect nor be surprised by any particular output or other behaviour.

Comment: @S.M. answer look reasonable, the code indeed wrong. But it shall give one behaviour because using same compiler(gcc).

Comment: This is the right answer. Anyone hoping for a segfault reliably should be made to read https://blog.regehr.org/archives/213 to develop a healthy sense of the pitfalls of UB.

Answer (score 0):

Which compiler do you use? If you use g++ compiler, i.e. the programming language is C++, the functions `b_helper` is inlined into the function `b`, and the function `b` is inlined into the function `a` in the release mode with enabled optimizations. In this case there are no more routings left that call `setjmp` and return.

Comment: Yes. I am using gcc (actually mingw32 5.3)