# Understanding the behaviour of setjmp and longjmp in C

Tags: c, unix, posix, embedded-linux

I understand that `setjmp` saves the content of the registers (sp,fp,pc) so that `longjmp` can restore them later. And when `longjmp` is called, it makes (kind of) setjmp return the passed `ret` val. However, in the below program, I am little confused with the flow.

```
1  #include <setjmp.h>
2  #include <stdio.h>
3 
4  jmp_buf env;
5 
6  void hello()
7  {
8         int ret = setjmp(env);
9         if(ret != 0)
10        {
11                printf("error\n");
12        }
13        printf("hello called\n");
14 }
15
16 int main() {
17        printf("hello main\n");
18        hello();
19        printf("after hello call\n");
20        longjmp(env,1);
21        printf("after long jump\n");
22        return 0;
23 }

Output (I was not expecting this)
---------------------------------
hello main
hello called
after hello call
error
hello called
```

I was expecting an endless loop here, because when `longjmp` gets called, the `ret` in hello should be 1 (which is as per output) but then, once `hello()` has returned at this point, I should have again fallen at line 19 and hence again calling `longjmp` at line 20. Please help me understand the behaviour here.

Comment: Pretty sure that it's UB to call `longjmp` after `hello` has returned to `main`.

Comment: This is undefined behavior; since the `setjmp` was done inside `hello`, you aren't allowed to `longjmp` there after `hello` has returned.  The idea is that `longjmp` is only supposed to go up the call stack.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SetJmp/LongJmp: Why is this throwing a segfault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381937/setjmp-longjmp-why-is-this-throwing-a-segfault)

Comment: @Jorengarenar Yes it does. Thanks.