# stating jmp_buf as pointer

Tags: c++, setjmp

I'm tring to define jmp_buf as pointer and using it in nested longjmp(s).as follow:

```
 ...
jmp_buf *bfj;
...
```

and then writing if else:

```
if( setjmp(*bfj) == 0){
DS[SP-2].int_val=(int)bfj;;
//to store the bfj
}else {}
```

and somewhere else using the stored bfj to longjmp

```
 bfj = (jmp_buf *)DS[TOP].int_val;
 longjmp(*bfj,1);
```

where DS[TOP].int_val is where I stored it.
as it may seems clear,I want to do nested gotos and returns using stored bfj.
but well when I try to debug I get "unhandeled exception". I get this at the very starting point:

```
if( setjmp(*bfj) == 0)
```

I would be pleased if someone would tell the solution.

Comment: You [have been told](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087268/question-with-longjmp) that what you're trying to do isn't a good idea. If you don't heed advice, what are you asking for?

Comment: I know it's not good idea to use longjmps but when you're tring to write a code that is near to assembly language for the output of the semantic phase of a compiler, it's the only solution get to my mind.so for the case that I'm writing, it's the way and yes it's not the good way.I must produce code that is near to assembly,(Three address code).
I never use goto or longjmp for regular programs but in this case,I have to produce such code. it's the natural of compilers.

Comment: No, it is not the "natural of compilers." A compiler is no different from any other program: All it does is translate some kind of input to some kind of output. The fact that you think you need to use `longjmp` (and that you clearly don't understand what it does or how it works) suggests you're doing something *very* wrong.

Comment: I've understood it.I said the third phase of compiler--->compiler course at university.not those regular and simple compilers you think. the compiler for Fortran has estimated 18 man year effort! It's not that simple as you think.(the regular definition of compilers)

Comment: I think it's a fair estimate to say that the _difference_ between two most recent Microsoft C++ compilers is 18 man-years of effort!  But greyfade is right: even a complex compiler is just transforming data structures.

Comment: I guess you don't see "compiler course at university" and you don't seem to know what is three address code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code, you are not actually allocating memory for your `jmp_buf`.  There are a couple of things you can do:

1. Dynamically allocate your `jmp_buf` with `new` and you will want to `delete` it when you are done with it
2. Put the `jmp_buf` on the stack `jmp_buf bfj;` and when you want it's pointer, you would take it's address with `&bfj`.

So, #1 would look like:

```
jmp_buf *bfj = new jmp_buf;
...

if( setjmp(*bfj) == 0){
DS[SP-2].int_val=(intptr_t)bfj;
```

while #2 would look like:

```
jmp_buf bfj;
...

if( setjmp(bfj) == 0){
DS[SP-2].int_val=(intptr_t)&bfj;
```

Another potential issue is that you should never cast a pointer to an `int` as a pointer may take more memory then an int (this happens on the common 64 bit programming models).  If you can't store the pointer directly, you should use `intptr_t` instead.

Comment: really thanks for your answer.but I get the error cannot convert from 'int *' to jmp_buf. what should I do?

Comment: @angela - did you use `int *` instead of `intptr_t` (they are not the same).

Comment: thanks!(you were right) but it seems that longjmp don't go back to setjmp.but somewhere else.is there any need to show my code?

Comment: well I traced the code and it showed that it's in a loop! it doesn't terminate.