# Giving labels as a argument in C/C++

Tags: c++11, goto

We  have a label:

```
LABEL:
    //Do something.
```

and we have a function. We want pass LABEL as a argument to this function (otherwise we can't access labels in a function), and in some condition we want to jump this label. Is it possible?

I'm giving a example (pseudocode) for clarification:

```
GameMenu: //This part will be executed when program runs
//Go in a loop and continue until user press to [ENTER] key

while(Game.running) //Main loop for game
{
    Game.setKey(GameMenu, [ESCAPE]); //If user press to [ESCAPE] jump into GameMenu
    //And some other stuff for game
}
```

Comment: You can't jump to a label outside of the current function.

Comment: @iwin: We don't know if that "C/C++" language does allow this. Apparently OP thinks C and C++ are the same language. They are **not**

Comment: @Olaf I was thinking of goto which wouldn't let you jump to an external label in either language, didn't know about setjmp / longjmp.

Comment: @iwin: Well, it works in BASIC and Assembler for instance. Without proper context, there is no really good answer, but only speculation. VTC as unclear. `goto` has its uses, but chances are quite good OP's is none of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). You might want a [state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine):

```
enum class State {
    menu,
    combat,
};

auto state = State::combat;
while (Game.running) {
    switch (state) {
    case State::combat:
        // Detect that Escape has been pressed (open menu).
        state = State::menu;
        break;

    case State::menu:
        // Detect that Escape has been pressed (close menu).
        state = State::combat;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like it may be worth refactoring your code to something similar:

```
void GameMenu() {
    // Show menu
}

void SomethingElse() {
    // Do something else
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    (...)

    while(Game.running) {
        int key = GetKey();
        switch(key) {
        case ESCAPE:
            GameMenu();
            break;
        case OTHER_KEY:
            SomethingElse();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`setjmp()/longjmp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/setjmp.h.html) to jump to some point in outer scope even to outer function. But note - jump target scope must be alive at the moment of jump.

Comment: Alive? What this means?

Comment: [setjmp and longjmp are very dangerous in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1376099/2491746).