# setjmp/longjmp in C++: Is this undefined behaviour?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, setjmp

Does the following code invoke undefined behaviour:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <csetjmp>

jmp_buf buffer1;
jmp_buf buffer2;

class Test
{
    public:
        ~Test()
        {
            std::cout << "Test destructor: " << this << std::endl;
        }
};

void p2()
{
    longjmp( buffer2, 1 );
}

void p1()
{
    {
        Test test;

        if ( setjmp( buffer2 ) == 0 )
        {
            p2();
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Jumping" << std::endl;
    longjmp( buffer1, 1 );
}

int main()
{
   if ( setjmp( buffer1 ) == 0 )
   {
       p1();
   }

   return 0;
}
```

With the intel compiler on windows *test*'s destructor gets called twice.  I logged this as a bug, however the intel developers claim this is undefined behaviour.  You can see our discussion [here](https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-C-Compiler/Bug-destructor-called-twice/m-p/1422616).  Every other compiler I tried did what I expected (aka called the destructor once).

The C++ standard says:

> If replacing std::longjmp with throw and setjmp with catch would invoke a non-trivial destructor for any automatic object, the behavior of such std::longjmp is undefined.

However it doesn't specify where the try should go and so if *test* is declared within the try block (leading to undefined behaviour) or before the try (which should not be UB).

My argument is that nothing before the setjmp could longjmp to its location, so logically the try should start at the setjmp.  However that is not explicitly part of what the standard says, so why couldn't it be extended to include more than necessary?

Comment: The intel developers are correct. setjmp/longjmp is a C library function that completely breaks fundamental C++ concepts. This is undefined behavior. setjmp/longjmp must never be used in C++ code. The good news is that there is a 100% C++ compatible replacement for setjmp/longjmp. It's called an exception.

Comment: The C++ standard defines when setjmp/longjmp can be used safely.

Comment: Exceptions can be much more expensive than setjmp/longjmp and there are certainly well-defined use for setjmp/longjmps. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1376085/3966456

Comment: As long as your code abides by the requirements of C++ standard setjmp/[longjmp](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/longjmp) (which in C++, has more restricted behavior for well-defined behavior than C) and when they can be used safely, then they can be used safely.  The code provided is an example of undefined behavior using setjmp/longjmp in C++.

Comment: Is there any reason you *need* to use `longjmp`? Outside of difficult, performance critical kernel code, I've never really seen a strong use case.

Comment: This is more of a language lawyer question than a help me with my code question, however since you asked, I am working with a legacy code base that used longjmp/setjmp extensively.  We have tried to remove as many as we could, but a few cases (in particular ones the interact with customer code) can't be removed without breaking compatibility.  I discovered this issue, logged the bug and moved on, until the intel devs said it wasn't a bug, triggering the conversion and ultimately the question.

Comment: If `test` is directly inside the scope of the body of `p1()` I agree it's UB. However with the nested scope I fail to see why. Can you elaborate @Eljay? I think it's a valid [tag:language-lawyer] question.

Comment: @user253751 My understanding is, whether or not test's declaration is within the try or not determines if test's destructor is called as part of the stack unwinding process of handling the exception.  If it is, then the setjmp/longjmp is UB.  If the declaration is not in the try, then its destructor is called as part of exiting the surrounding scope, so this is not UB.

Comment: Assume you have an extra line that refers to the `test` right after the `if`. If `test` is declared in the try block, it is impossible to write a valid `try/catch` form without invalidating that extra line.

Comment: @user253751 I think you misunderstood what I am meant.  The C++ standard describes when it is not undefined behaviour to use longjmp by "converting" the setjmp/longjmp to a throw/catch.  If any non-trivial destructors need to be called it is indeed UB.  This example may be ambiguous as to whether or not test's destructor could be called in this conversion.

Comment: @user253751 My understanding of what the standard say is if the destructor of test would be called handling the substituted throw->catch then the code is UB.  If it is not, then the code is not UB.  Whether or not test's destructor is called seems to depend on if test is part of the try block or not.  The intel dev's position is that the standard doesn't specify, so they can make test's declaration part of the try block and thus make this UB.

Comment: As I said if you have more complex code you can't get a equivalent try/catch if you require the declaration to be part of the try block.

Comment: You know what - I'm an idiot, as I thought you meant to jump to buffer2 from the end of p1.

Comment: @WeijunZhou I tried adding a method to Test and calling that after the if.  It still calls the destructor twice.  I added that to the bug report.  Let's see what they say.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the code modified as the standard discusses comes out like this (I've left the `setjmp` and `longjmp` in place as comments to make it clear what I've changed). I have added one extra annotation, so we can see when each exception is thrown.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <csetjmp>

// jmp_buf buffer1;
// jmp_buf buffer2;

class Test
{
    public:
        ~Test()
        {
            std::cout << "Test destructor: " << this << std::endl;
        }
};

void p2()
{
    std::cerr << "Jumping from p2\n";
    throw 1;
    // longjmp( buffer2, 1 );
}

void p1()
{
    {
        Test test;

        try
        {
            p2();
        }
        catch(...) {
            std::cerr << "caught in p1\n";
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Jumping" << std::endl;
    // longjmp( buffer1, 1 );
    throw 1;
}

int main()
{
   try
   {
       p1();
   }
   catch (...) {
    std::cerr << "caught in main\n";
   }

   return 0;
}
```

When we run this, we get:

```
Jumping from p2
caught in p1
Test destructor: 0x7ffdff2c9a3f
Jumping
caught in main
```

The dtor is not invoked in the process of handling an exception, so the original code has defined behavior.

Comment: That was my interpretation as well, however the standard doesn't say you couldn't include the declaration of test within the try.  It doesn't specify where the try should go.  I think it is the obvious interpretation, maybe even the intended interpretation, but I'm not sure the language actually requires it.

Comment: @dohashi: It says you replace the `setjmp` with `catch` and the `longjmp` with `throw`, so the `try` and `catch` should go exactly where the `setjmp` and `longjmp` were.

Comment: As far as I can tell, and I am not a language lawyer, the standard doesn't say the try has to be positioned where the setjmp is.  It doesn't explicitly mention where the try should be placed.  I really want you to be right, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @dohashi: I don't see how it can be much clearer than it is. I don't see any way that "Replace the setjmp with catch and the longjmp with throw" can be read as meaning: "Replace the setjmp with catch and the longjmp with throw and then rearrange everything else in some completely arbitrary fashion."

Comment: @dohashi What if you add an else branch to your `if(setjmp...`? Can you use that to convince the Intel people?

Comment: @JerryCoffin Imagine the declaration of test is within the try.  Where does the standard say that is not a valid conversion?  This is why I tagged this with language-lawyer.

Comment: @WeijunZhou I don't think so.  This is more about what comes before the setjmp, not after.

Comment: @dohashi: Jesus F'ing Christ! "Replace X with Y" does not mean "replace X with Y, then rearrange everything else arbitrarily" How much simpler can this be?